Curve fitting SCILAB/MATHLAB divergence explanation
I am completing a workshop in which I am given a set of data. I then have to predict future data points outside of the data range.
I interpreted the data graphically and figured that it could be approximated by a sinusoidal function of the following type:
f(t) = Asin(WT + k) + at + b
I have written code that does the following:
Finds a rough initial fitting of the parameters of the function to ensure faster convergence, then a code that evaluates the error margin between f(t) and each data point with the L2 norm. After that through a recursive algorithm it will create a bit of noise and evaluate the error of the new noisy parameters and compare it with the initial fitting. And decide which has the less error and move forth with the new fitting.
My question comes now, depending on how much noise and how many times I run through the algorithm, I'll get ludicrous results.
On the current model, I'll get good results while running through the loop 100 times, but 1000 will be less precise than the initial fitting! Also, if I start with a line, I will diverge whatever noise/iterations I input.
Are there any papers I could read about curve fitting convergence/divergence I could read since I'm extremely new to the field. Also does anyone have a clue why this is happening?
My code was reviewed and doesn't contain any logical flaws, I do think I am lacking on curve fitting theory however...
Here is the code with PARA being the initial parameters.
function y = MODEL(x, PARA)

    y = PARA(1)*sin(A(:,1)'*PARA(2))+PARA(4) + PARA(5)*A(:,1)' + PARA(6)

endfunction


function err = myerror(PARA,A)
    B=zeros(size(A,1))
    B = PARA(1)*sin(A(:,1)'*PARA(2))+PARA(4) + PARA(5)*A(:,1)' + PARA(6) - A(:,1)'
    err = norm(B,2)
endfunction

function NPARA = fit_rand(PARA, A, err, N)
    M = zeros(1,N+1)
    
    M(1) = myerror(PARA,A)
    NOISE = 0.2
    for i = 1:N
        I = rand(1,6) - 0.5
        I = I*NOISE
        NPARA = PARA + I.*PARA
        M(i+1) = myerror(NPARA,A)
        if (err(NPARA, A) < err(PARA, A)-1)
            PARA = NPARA
        end
    end
    
endfunction


I doubt the code works in the way you describe. Indications are * It never references MODEL or PARA(3) * Nothing is "recursive." * Where is the "rough initial fitting"? * Where is any fitting routine invoked at all? -- It looks like a completely random search of a limited space of parameter values. // A good resource for those who need to get the job done and learn a little theory while doing it is the Numerical Recipes book, https://numerical.recipes/. BTW, Matlab has a rich set of nonlinear optimization functions, https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/nonlinear-programming.html.

Thanks for the ressources, I didn't include the initial fitting because it works quite well, in this code it gives the PARA vector. Model isn't referenced because I'm already putting the equation in the code, I'll optimize it once it starts working! The recursive part I believe is what the lines 19-27 do. They take initial parameters, add a bit of noise, then see if the new noisy parameters are better, if so PARA takes the new parameters if not, we add different noise (random) and see if it works better thus optimizing the margin of error between the data and the function.

Please look up the meaning of "recursive."  Maybe you mean "iterative."  In this context, a recursive algorithm might be one that finds an approximate optimum under certain constraints, makes those constraints more restrictive as a consequence, and then calls itself to improve the solution subject to the more restrictive constraints.  Thus, this is not just a quibble over terminology: it gets down to how you think your search actually works.

Fiting an equation model which includes periodoc function(s) is a wide problem. Many approaches can be proposed more or less convenient depending on the data. I doubt that an efficient method exists for all cases. You should raise your question on a more restricted range and on a more concrete manner. At least provide a representative example of data (on numerical form, not graphical). This will make much easier to explain a proposed method and why the proposed method is more convenient than another one. Doing this in the general case (without example) would be too extensive.

The usual way to do nonlinear regression is to use the gradient of the outcome with respect to predictor values to adjust parameter estimates to minimize the mean-square error criterion. I'm not sure what you are trying to gain by adding noise to the parameter values instead. One of the biggest problems in nonlinear regression is that small changes in initial/intermediate parameter estimates can send you to a local optimum far from the global optimum that you seek. See this page, for example. If you start adding your own noise to the intermediate parameter estimates, you would seem to be at even greater risk of ending up where you don't want to be.
The vignette for the R nlstools package provides a good introduction to the problems in nonlinear regression, with references.
In this particular case, it looks like you might avoid all those problems by converting your equation to a model that is linear in the parameters and can be solved by ordinary least squares. A sinusoidal function with a phase shift can be written as a sum of sine and cosine terms without phase shifts; see this page, this page, or this page for examples. The model is then linear in the coefficients of the sine and cosine terms. If there's a well-defined cycle time based on subject matter knowledge (as there is for time of day or wind direction), then that would be the way to proceed.

Thank you very much, I'll check out the ressources and try changing the model to a sin and cosin function.
Regarding the noise, I have a pretty decent initial model, so I thought that by adding noise and then seeing if the function with noise has a lesser error than the one without, it would slowly optimize my function. But I think it might've just caused me problems!
